# How to dynamically request a React Component based on a variable value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering how to dynamically request a component based on a variable value. What I'm trying to accomplish here is the following:

```
import Template1 from './Template1.jsx';
import Template2 from './Template2.jsx';

var ComponentTemplate = (some_condition === true) ? "Template1" : "Template2"

render() {
    <ComponentTemplate prop1="prop1 val" />
}
```

Is this even possible? If so, how?

Comment: What do the strings like `"Template1"` represent?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller the actual names of a component. I updated the text to add some clarity

Comment: You mean like a string representation of a class name?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller yes, exactly.

Comment: Could you just put the `render` itself within the conditional statement? Or just set the variable to the React template component itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear to me why you need to use a string representation of a class rather than just switch the component or use a conditional render:

```js
var Component = some_condition === true ? Template1 : Template2;
// ...
return ( <Component /> );
```

But assuming this is an oversimplification, the easiest thing to do would be to use a mapping object that translates a string into a component. With ES2015 [enhanced object literals](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#enhanced-object-literals), it becomes fairly straightforward:

```js
var Components = {
  Template1,
  Template2,
};

var Component = condition ? Components['Template1'] : Components['Template2'];

// ...

return ( <Component /> );
```

Comment: Nope, I think you nailed it the first time around.

Comment: It won't work I think. Because the React will compile the JSX tag by variable name. If you place Component to JSX. It will be React.createElement('Component') as well. It make no sense to using your original one.

Comment: @hlissnake I don't think I followed that, but it definitely will work. `React.createElement` takes *either* a string or a React class. It won't stringify a function/class. The call would actually be `React.createElement( Component, {} );`, where `Component` is a reference to a place in memory housing a function definition.

Comment: @Josh David Miller yes you are right. for primitive tag like 'span', 'div', it will compile into String. for element Class it will turn into Class object. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to render different component based on the condition you could actually have 2 other render function and inside render() you could check the condition and call corresponding render

```
render () {
  !this.state.isAuthorized? renderLogin(): renderTweets();
}

renderLogin () {
   <LoginView/>
}

renderTweet () {
   <ListTweets/>
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: That's the correct way to define different React element

Answer (score 0):

All the dynamic rendering should inside Render function. Because the JSX compile will depend on the Variable name not the Object reference.

If you write `<Component />`, 
it will transfer to `React.createElement('Component')`.

Cannot refer to the dynamic component you want to choose.

depend on the condition when Render is running. Use different React tag you want.

```
render() {
    condition ? <Template1 /> : <Template2 />
}
```